# Bootstrap panel not getting extended

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I am making a social networking site, this code here is a part of a panel which shows the posts.The problem is it is showing the comments on toggle but the comments are not appearing within the footer it is crossing it...So what is wrong in my or how can I extend the panel footer?

**Here's the code:**

```
<div class="panel-footer"> 
Like <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick="javascript:toggle<?php echo $idp?>()" style="color:black">Comments</a>
    <div id='toggleComment<?php echo $idp;?>' style="display:none;">
    <form action="" method="POST"><!--FORM COMMENT-->
    <div class="form-group">                        
        <div class="rows" >
        <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-right:2px;">
        <div class="compic">
                <img src="<?php echo $profilepic; ?>" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-11" style="padding-left:3px; padding-bottom:7px">
              <textarea class="form-control expandable pull-left" name="comment<?php echo $idp;?>" id="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." required>
                    </textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="subcom<?php echo $idp;?>"><b>Comment</b></button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div></form>
    <div class="rows" >
    <?php
    $postid=$idp;
    $postby=$id;
    $postto=$uid;
    if(isset($_POST['subcom'.$postid]))
    {   $postbody=$_POST['comment'.$postid];
        if($postbody!="")
        {$res=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comment VALUES('','$postby','$postto','$postbody','$postid')");}           
    }
    $show=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postid='$idp' ORDER by id");
    while($show_row=mysqli_fetch_array($show))
    {
        $commentbyid=$show_row['cby'];
        $combody=$show_row['cbody'];
                $cbyquery=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$commentbyid'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                $cby=mysqli_fetch_array($cbyquery);
                $cpic=$cby['profpic'];
                if ($cpic== "" || !file_exists("userdata/profile_pics/$cpic"))
                {
                    $cpic = "images/default_pic.jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    $cpic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$cpic;
                }
                $cname=ucfirst(strtolower($cby[1]));
                $csname=ucfirst(strtolower($cby[2]));
            ?>
                <div class="col-sm-1" style="padding-right:2px;">
                    <div class="compic">
                        <img src="<?php echo $cpic; ?>" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-11" style="padding-left:3px;">
                <?php echo $cname." ".$csname;?><br>
                <?php echo $combody;?>
                </div>
            <?php
    }
    ?></div>
    </div><!--Toggle Ends here-->               
</div>
```

Comment: no its still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got it it was because of the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` and it got solved when I used it just after  `</div><!--Toggle Ends here-->`